# MapReduce on MongoDB collection is turning up empty

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I've been trying to bring many large sets of data down into one collection, but I'm having issues writing a MapReduce function to get there.

This is what my data looks like (here are 17 rows, in reality I have 4+ million):

```
{"user": 1, "day": 1, "type": "a", "sum": 10}
{"user": 1, "day": 2, "type": "a", "sum": 32}
{"user": 1, "day": 1, "type": "b", "sum": 11}
{"user": 2, "day": 4, "type": "b", "sum": 2}
{"user": 1, "day": 2, "type": "b", "sum": 1}
{"user": 1, "day": 3, "type": "b", "sum": 9}
{"user": 1, "day": 4, "type": "b", "sum": 12}
{"user": 2, "day": 2, "type": "a", "sum": 3}
{"user": 3, "day": 2, "type": "b", "sum": 81}
{"user": 1, "day": 4, "type": "a", "sum": 22}
{"user": 1, "day": 5, "type": "a", "sum": 39}
{"user": 2, "day": 5, "type": "a", "sum": 8}
{"user": 2, "day": 3, "type": "b", "sum": 1}
{"user": 3, "day": 3, "type": "b", "sum": 99}
{"user": 2, "day": 3, "type": "a", "sum": 5}
{"user": 1, "day": 3, "type": "a", "sum": 41}
{"user": 3, "day": 4, "type": "b", "sum": 106}
...
```

I'm trying to get it to look like this in the end (an array for each type, where the contents are just the sums in the appropriate index decided by the day, if that day doesn't exist for that type, it's just 0):

```
{"user": 1, "type_a_sums": [10, 32, 41, 22, 39], "type_b_sums": [11, 1, 9, 12, 0]}
{"user": 2, "type_a_sums": [0, 3, 5, 0, 8], "type_b_sums": [0, 0, 1, 2, 0]}
{"user": 3, "type_a_sums": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], "type_b_sums": [0, 81, 99, 106, 0]}
...
```

This is the MapReduce I have been trying:

```
var mapsum = function(){
    var output = {user: this.user, type_a_sums: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], type_b_sums: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], tempType: this.type, tempSum: this.sum, tempDay: this.day}

    if(this.type == "a") {
        output.type_a_sums[this.day-1] = this.sum;
    }

    if(this.type == "b") {
        output.type_b_sums[this.day-1] = this.sum;
    }

    emit(this.user, output);
};

var r = function(key, values) {
    var outs = {user: 0, type_a_sums: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], type_b_sums: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], tempType: -1, tempSum: -1, tempDay: -1}

    values.forEach(function(v){

        outs.user = v.user;

        if(v.tempType == "a") {
            outs.type_a_sums[v.tempDay-1] = v.tempSum;
        }

        if(v.tempType == "b") {
            outs.type_b_sums[v.tempDay-1] = v.tempSum;
        }

    });

    return outs;
};


res = db.sums.mapReduce(mapsum, r, {out: 'joined_sums'})
```

This gives me my output on the small sample, but when I run it over all 4 million I get a ton of outputs that look like this:

```
{"user": 1, "type_a_sums": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], "type_b_sums": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
{"user": 2, "type_a_sums": [0, 3, 5, 0, 8], "type_b_sums": [0, 0, 1, 2, 0]}
{"user": 3, "type_a_sums": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], "type_b_sums": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

Where a large portion of `users` that should have sums in their arrays are actually just filled with the 0's that were in the dummy array in the `reduce` functions `outs` object before I fill it up with the actual function.

What's really weird is if I run the same exact function on the same collection but only check for one user `res = db.sums.mapReduce(mapsum, r, {query: {user: 1}, out: 'joined_sums'})` that I know should have sums in their arrays but has been previously been turning up as all 0's, I will actually get the output I wanted for just that user. Run it again over all 4 million and I'm back to 0's everywhere. It's like it's just writing over all the work it did with the dummy filler arrays.

Do I have too much data? Shouldn't it be able to slog through it given the time? Or am I hitting some barrier I don't know about?

Comment: Any chance its a bug in an outdated version of MongoDB?

Comment: I think it has to do with `reduce()` being called more than once per key. I'm trying to use `finalize`, but I'm very confused as to how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for including lots of detail. There are a few issues here.

Let's start from the top.

> I'm trying to get it to look like this in the end
>
> {"user": 2, "type_a_sums": [0, 3, 5, 0, 8], "type_b_sums": [0, 0, 1, 2, 0]}

It will actually look like this:

```
{ _id: { "user": 2 }, value: { "type_a_sums": [0, 3, 5, 0, 8], "type_b_sums": [0, 0, 1, 2, 0] }
```

Note that `_id` is kind of like your "group by" and `value` is kind of like your "sum" columns.

So problem #1 is that you are emitting `user` as your key, but it's also part of your value. This is not necessary. The reduce will only reduce two values that share the same key, you don't need this line either: `outs.user = v.user;`

You also have **problem #2: your `reduce` is incorrect**.

> I think it has to do with reduce() being called more than once per key.

The goal of `reduce()` is that it will be called multiple times. It is supposed to scale across servers. So one server could call reduce a couple of times and those results could be merged and sent to another server.

Here's a different way to look at it. **Reduce takes an array of `value` objects and reduces them to a single `value` object**.

There are some corollaries here:

- If I do `reduce([a, b])`, it should be the same as `reduce([b, a])`.
- If I do `reduce([a, reduce([b,c]))` it should be the same as `reduce([reduce([a,b]), c])`

So it should not matter what order I run them in or how many times the value gets reduced, it's always the same output.

If you look at your code, this is not what's happening. Just take a look at the `type_a_sums`. What happens if I get the following two `values` coming to reduce?

```
reduce([ [0,0,1,0,0], [0,2,0,0,0] ]) => ???
```

To me, this looks like the output should be `[0,2,1,0,0]`. If this is true, then you don't need all of those `temp_X` fields. Instead, you need to focus on `emit`ing the correct arrays and then merging those arrays correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed the code (http://pastie.org/private/dc9gizrsrzckzq6hvjkqq), but won't be able to run it until the morning. I removed the temp values and instead changed the code in `reduce()` to add the elements of each `emit()` array to the corresponding element in the `reduce()` output array. Does that make more sense?

I don't understand why using just arrays would help though. Why won't adding the elements from the `temp` variables work just as well. This way, I'm just using an array's elements to add up instead of an `int`, but I feel like it's the same thing. Do I need `finalize`?

Comment: This *looks* much better. The reason you don't need the temps is that the output of an emit *could* be the final result. It may *not* be, but it *could* be. Given that what you really want at the end of the day are the arrays, you want the arrays to be correct at each phase.